# Scheduling a Task for every minute in Windows server 2016

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I need to schedule a Task inside of my Windows server 2016 to run every minute, how would one accomplish that?
I've tried Task Scheduler->Create Task, but the minimum is every 5 minutes,
Is it to possible to schedule task (run exe) every minute ?
any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can set 1 minute frequency through task scheduler itself. The option does not appear in the dropdown list, but you can edit the text and it will accept a variety of values from `1 minute` upwards.

Comment: I confirm that it works on Windows Server 2016. This should be the accepted answer.